# Postgres IO bottleneck

Tags: postgresql, performance-tuning

I'm getting consistent 100% IO utilisation with quite low overall throughput, which is causing system slow down, I'm unsure whether this is a 'real' IO limit or the result of configuration and circumstances.

A bit of background: We have dedicated primary and warm standby boxes. The primary is shared with the core application which routinely causes lots of updates of small records. Tables are written back to themselves with updated data. All of the table schemas are just ID and JSONB columns, all the data exists in the JSONB field. There are lots of tables, many with several million rows. The queries are often trivial selects, sometimes with a simple WHERE, or ORDER BY, but no JOINs. The default insert operation is an upsert-merge. The primary has around 10TB over three LVM volumes with XFS on a RAID10 array (8x7200RPM rust).

We recently encountered very full disks (99%), and discovered the XFS partitions were highly fragmented. I've run xfs_fsr which has reduced the frag factor but hasn't done much for performance. Now running at more like 90% capacity (~800GB free).

Another incident was a table was deadlocked for around a month which I think (?) caused autovacuum to get stuck, resulting in lots of `WARNING:  oldest xmin is far in the past HINT:  Close open transactions soon to avoid wraparound problems.` which was resolved by clearing the deadlock and expediting vacuum.

Primary is 40 cores with 96GB RAM running CentOS 7.9 PG version 9.6, connections are transaction pool through pgbouncer.

postgres.conf tuning params: ('Data Warehouse' from https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/)

```
max_connections = 256
shared_buffers = 6GB
effective_cache_size = 18GB
work_mem = 12MB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
min_wal_size = 4GB
max_wal_size = 8GB
#checkpoint_completion_target = 0.5
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 500
```

Output from `atop -d`

```
LVM |   das1-crypto  |   busy    101%  |  read    4008  |  write    555   |  avio 2.19 ms  |
LVM |    centos-var  |   busy    100%  |  read    3407  |  write   1335   |  avio 2.10 ms  |
LVM |  das1-storage  |   busy     99%  |  read    3122  |  write    211   |  avio 2.96 ms  |
DSK |           sdb  |   busy    101%  |  read    7132  |  write    766   |  avio 1.27 ms  |
DSK |           sda  |   busy    101%  |  read    3492  |  write   1504   |  avio 2.00 ms  |
```

sda (centos-var) and sdb (das1-*) are on different spindles.

Overall throughput (from iotop) is in the order of 10's of M/s read and write.

Snapshot from pgadmin4:
[image]

Incidentally, the warm standby (WAL file shipping, RAID5) is barely keeping up with the changes, frequently with several thousand WAL file backlog.

I'm an my limit for understanding the factors at play, should my RAID arrays be capable of sustaining a dozen or so fairly intensive upsert-merges? My intuition is that something is very wrong, that the disks shouldn't be a 100% utilisation at such low throughput... unless something is causing loads of seeks, such as high fragmentation rates?...

Any thoughts / insights / more diagnostics appreciated. Alternatively, if anyone can recommend a good postgres consultant that would be helpful too! Thanks!

Comment: You should upgrade with haste.  Monitoring abilities have been improved since 9.6.  In the mean time, what does the wait_event column of pg_stat_activity show?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a longer consulting session.

Comment: @jjanes thanks. `wait_event` from `pg_stat_activity` is blank. Unforrunately our upgrade path right now is severely limited by constant data collection :(

Comment: General steps would be to identify the exact processes that are responsible for the IO requirements, then find out why they use so much. Your description of your application is very vague, but it could be interpreted that your app loads everything without filters sometimes, that could be a bad idea. One obvious solution to stop the pain is to move on from spinning disks, SSDs are many times faster and scalable than HDD, budget for additional growth now (buy double capacity) and you should be fine. No one likes throwing hardware at a problem but it will buy you time to learn the software side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that spinning rust just can't keep up with the required IOPS from the workload. 8 x 7200RPM HDDs can achieve around / upto 500 IOPS, that's clearly being maxed out (IOWAITS > 5%). It seems the workload consists of too many random read/writes.